# How to search for git commits with differences regexp in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, egit

`git log -G regexp` can be used to search for differences in commits, but I cannot find how to do this operation in Eclipse. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

To give an answer, I'm pretty sure there is no way to do this in Eclipse.  Git has numerous subcommands and options.  Eclipse uses the git interface to perform numerous tasks specific to operating on files in Eclipse.  Git provides many other features that don't fit directly with an Eclipse feature.